# How to redirect from the current route to completely different URL added query parms

Tags: angular

I want to redirect with Router and added query params but after call function  error appears:

> "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes."

Function is like this:

```
const url = 'https://test.com' + '?queryParam=' + word;
this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
```

Comment: `window.location='https://test.com' + '?queryParam=' + word` should work

Comment: Redirect **where**?

Comment: Yes, but is there way with router.navigate or something like this. Thanks. @LppEdd I want to navigate to other url. For example now my app is at localhost:1000/test i want to go to localhost:2000/?queryParam=Apple

Comment: Please try to come up with esplicative questions, we can't always go by interpretation.

Comment: @NicoSandros `window.location` then. `Router` is reserved for the current application.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following for navigating within your angular application with query parameters:

`this.router.navigate(["/test"], { queryParams: { foo: "bar" }});`

if you need to navigate outside your angular application then you could try

`window.location.href = 'https://test.com' + '?queryParam=' + word;`